# Webpack 5 plugin update

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

I am currently using vue-automatic-import-loader to automatically import buefy components in vue2 SFC using webpack 4. I managed to update the project to use webpack 5, but unfortunately this plugin does not work with webpack 5 and the project is no longer active. Does anyone know how to convert this JavaScript file to support webpack 5?

https://github.com/hunterliu1003/vue-automatic-import-loader/blob/master/lib/plugin.js

```
const RuleSet = require('webpack/lib/RuleSet')
let vueLoaderPath
try {
  vueLoaderPath = require.resolve('vue-loader')
} catch (err) {}

function isVueLoader (use) {
  return use.ident === 'vue-loader-options' ||
    use.loader === 'vue-loader' ||
    (vueLoaderPath && use.loader === vueLoaderPath)
}

class VueAutoMaticImportPlugin {
  constructor (options) {
    this.options = options
  }

  apply (compiler) {
    // use webpack's RuleSet utility to normalize user rules
    const rawRules = compiler.options.module.rules
    const { rules } = new RuleSet(rawRules)

    // find the rule that applies to vue files
    let vueRuleIndex = rules.findIndex(rule => rule.use && rule.use.find(isVueLoader))
    const vueRule = rules[vueRuleIndex]

    if (!vueRule) {
      throw new Error(
        `[VueAutoMaticImportPlugin Error] No matching rule for vue-loader found.\n` +
        `Make sure there is at least one root-level rule that uses vue-loader.`
      )
    }

    vueRule.use.unshift({
      loader: require.resolve('./loader'),
      options: this.options
    })

    compiler.options.module.rules = rules
  }
}

module.exports = VueAutoMaticImportPlugin
```